# Multitenancy in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Regarding the actual limitations in querying data based on subcollections values, what is the suggested way to manage multitenancy in Firestore?

I would like to be able to retrieve and limit access to data related to entities/companies the user is part of.

Example data structure :

```
/companies/{companyId}/users/
/companies/{companyId}/users/{user}/roles
/companies/{companyId}/docs/
```

Can `/companies/{companyId}/users/` be a collection?

How can I only retrieve companies where user own a role in `/companies/{companyId}/users` ?

Comment: It's typically recommended to use separate projects for different environments rather than put them all together in one project.  You'll have far better isolation and access control to each Firebase product if you do it that way.

Comment: @DougStevenson Please say tell me that that has changed by now. That's a horrible way to do do multi-tenancy, especially since there doesn't seem to be an API for actually creating new projects.

Comment: @DennisKrøger Nothing has changed, and nothing is likely to change.  This has always been the recommendation of the Firebase team.

Comment: @DougStevenson This (along with missing user invite functionality) is the main issue that has prompted us to go for AWS instead. Their multi-tenancy still isn't great, but at least it's doable with new customers/tenants signing themselves up. If we were to use the recommended Firebase approach, we would have to have someone adding tenants manually, when there is no project creation API. Not going to happen.

It's quite a shame, since almost everything else seemed to match our use case perfectly.

Comment: This could help: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy

Comment: we can use gcid multiple tenants now, but I have no idea on how to implements this with angularfire2, there is almost no documentation

Comment: The article mentioned by @christostsang seems to refer to Google Datastore in "Datastore Mode", while the question is about Firebase (which is "Native Mode")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore paths alternate from collection to document and back again:

```
/collection/document/subcollection/subdocument
```

So yes, in this case, you would have collections of `companies`, `users`, and `docs`. Collections are also **implicit** in that they are created automatically when documents exist in them, and removed when no documents exist in them.

At present, subcollection queries (e.g. "all users in a given company") aren't supported, so you'll have to structure your query the other way around: having a users collection with company as a property, when performing a query to find all users in that company.

```
ref.collection('users').where('company', '==', 'ACME').get().then((document) => {/* Do stuff here */});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mike-mcdonald

Comment: @mike-mcdonald Can you talk about or point me to how this relates to user authentication? I want to also limit a user's access, I feel like what we need to do is be able to assign a company id to a user and then limit reads/writes on sub-documents with that company id assigned to it. 
Otherwise in this example wouldn't a user have access to all other user's data? Thanks!